# Content Provider in AndroidManifest

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm developing an hybrid app with Apache Cordova. Due to a bug with file choosing in forms in Android 4.4 I had to sort it with an android plugin.

This plugin lets you upload a file to a php server using ajax.

The problem is that this plugin comes with a 3rd party library that adds a Content Provider to AndroidManifest.xml. Following [instructions](https://github.com/cdibened/filechooser) from the plugin developer this ContentProvider should be changed.

> Note that like a ContentProvider, the DocumentProvider authority must be unique. 
>       You should change com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents in your Manifest, as 
>       well as the LocalStorageProvider.AUTHORITY field.

This is what the plugins adds to AndroidManifest.xml

```
provider android:authorities="com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents" android:enabled="@bool/use_provider" android:exported="true" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.LocalStorageProvider" android:permission="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.content.action.DOCUMENTS_PROVIDER" />
  </intent-filter>
</provider>
```

In this [library](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) there's a class named LocalStorageProvider.java where AUTHORITY is fixed:

**public class LocalStorageProvider extends DocumentsProvider {
    public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.ianhanniballake.localstorage.documents";**

The question is: What should I put instead of com.ianhanniballake.localstorage? Because if no change is done I can not have a test and a release version of my app installed in my phone as a **CONTENT PROVIDER MUST BE UNIQUE** message arises.

Thanks in advance. Manel.

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html

> android:authorities A list of one or more URI authorities that
>   identify data offered by the content provider. Multiple authorities
>   are listed by separating their names with a semicolon. To avoid
>   conflicts, authority names should use a Java-style naming convention
>   (such as com.example.provider.cartoonprovider). Typically, it's the
>   name of the ContentProvider subclass that implements the provider
>   There is no default. At least one authority must be specified.

So maybe subclass that ContentProvider and provide use `packagename.classname`